# when i import react i got an error about react is declared but its value is never read

Tags: reactjs

import React
'React' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)
'React' is defined but never used.

```
import React from "react";
import reactDom from "react-dom";
```

Comment: Yeh, it is fine. In the latest version of react.js you don't have to import. You can learn more in react docs or in this article https://dev.to/titungdup/you-no-longer-need-to-import-react-from-react-3pbj

Comment: Just remove that import

Comment: what version of react are you usiong ?

Answer (score 0):

go to to **webpack.config.js** file   located in `....\node_modules\react-scripts\config\webpack.config.js` . and add to it :

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      React: 'react'
    })
  ]
```

this  will Automatically load react instead of having to import it everywhere . you can check it [here](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/)